# How to tells Knative Pod Autoscaler not to kill in-progress long running pod

Tags: autoscaling, knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing

**My goal:**
Implement a cron job run once per week and I intend to implement this topology on Knative to save the computing resources:

PingSource -> knative service

The PingSource will emit a dummy event to a knative service once per week just to bring up 1 knative service pod. The knative service pod will get huge amount of data and then process them.

**My concern:**
If I set `enable-scale-to-zero` to true, the Knative pod autoscaler probably shutdown the knative service pod even when the pod has not finished its work.

**So far, I explored:**

- The `scale-to-zero-grace-period` which can be configured to tell the auto scaler how long it should wait after the last traffic ends to shutdown the pod. But I don't think this approach is subtle. I prefer somewhat similar to readinessProbe or livenessProbe. The auto scaler should send a probe to know whether the pod is processing something before sending the kill signal.
- In addition, according to knative's docs, there are 2 type of event sink: callable and addressable. Addressable and Callable both return the response or acknowledgement. Would the knative auto scaler consider the pod as handling the request till the pod return the response/acknowledgement? So as long as the pod does not response, it won't be removed by the auto scaler.

Answer (score 1):

The Knative autoscaler relies on the pod strictly working in a request/response fashion. As long as the "huge amount of data" is processed as part of an HTTP request (or Websocket session, or gRPC session etc.) the pod will not even be considered for deletion.

What will not work is sending the request, immediately return and then munging the data in the background. The autoscaler will think that there's no activity at all and thus shut it down. There is a [sandbox project](https://github.com/knative-sandbox/async-component/) that tries to implement such asynchronous semantics though.